# How do I add a view underneath a Table View, but it scrolls with the cells?

Tags: ios, swift

I want a Table View that has very basic cells. However, at the end of the cells (if any), I want to show a button and some labels (let's call this infoView).  I want the infoView to follow the scroll of the Table View.

If there are 20 rows, for example, the infoView wouldn't be shown until the user scrolls all the way down. It would act like a cell.

Is there a way to achieve this in a simple manner? Should the infoView be a cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a `TableFooterView` for the `UITableView`.

If you are using storyboard, you probably have prototype cells there as well. Simply pick a view and place it below those cells as shown in the following image:

[image]

[image]

This view will now act as a `TableFooterView`. You can resize it and add whatever you want to, and those components will come at the bottom of the `UITableView` when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom.